# ASP NET c# disable autopostback after clicking back button in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, autopostback, .net

i have a listbox in my asp page, when user clicks any of items, the page is redirected to other page. To do that i used the SelectedIndexChanged event, but it wasnt firing, so i change the autopostback property of listbox to true. Everything is forking fine now, except when i click back button in browser, it redirects to the first page, and than back to last one, because of the selected index of a listbox. Any suggestions? Thanks, Oak

Comment: Where does classic asp come in ?

Answer (score 1):

You should verify `IsPostBack` property of your page. If `!IsPostBack` do your work.

Comment: Not working anyway, it is redirecting when the listbox is clicked for the first time, and than when i press back button, or the event is not being fired at all.